# Missing Ethernet driver after downgrading to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ethernet, lenovo-laptop, downgrade

I've recently installed Windows 7 on a Lenovo M30-70 Notebook.  It came with Windows 8 as default.

I delete all partitions when I downgrade/upgrade.  My main issue is that I am missing multiple drivers, however, the Ethernet controller is the one I am in desperate need of.

Hardware ID's: PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&subsys_380617AA&REV_08
PCI\VEN_10ED&DEV_8136&SUBSYS_380617AA
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&CC_020000
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&CC_0200

I tried installing the Realtek driver for the Windows 8 version of the same model laptop but that did not install.

Can anyone advise on what I should do?

Comment: It may be that the manufacturer has not supplied a Windows 7 compatible driver for your hardware it would be best to contact them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136` = Realtek 10/100/1000 PCI-E NIC. [Download and install](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) the Windows 7 driver (`Install_Win7_7088_07242014.zip`) from Realtek.